# How to fix this syntax error in the code given below?

Tags: python, python-2.7

code is-

```
class Map(object):

scenes = [
    'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
    'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
    'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
    'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
    'death': Death()
]
```

the python interpreter is stuck at line " 'central_corridor' : CentralCorridor()" where the :(colon) is marked to be a syntax error. Scenes is list of all the classes  made earlier in the program.

Comment: [Don't use LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).

Comment: deed is already done. Any suggesttion on how to remove this error?

Comment: You seem to be making a hybrid dict/list, which do you want?

Comment: . Trying to learn by coding. Here storing each scene by name in Map class in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two syntax errors in your code.

- Python classes must contain at least one indented line.
- Dictionaries are surrounded with `{}`, not `[]`

My best guess is that this is what you want.

```
class Map(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.scenes = {
            'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
            'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
            'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
            'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
            'death': Death(),
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? If so, it should be enclosed in curly braces `{ }`:

```
scenes = {"central_corridor": CentralCorridor()}
```

Square brackets `[ ]` are used for [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Well when I try using parenthesis , the program doesnt run at all. i meant that no action at all.

Comment: @khushboogupta please edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: @khushboogupta This solves the problem you raised in your question; any problem you are having now will need to be raised in a new question. Please accept this answer.